# Multi tenant Flutter application linked with AWS silo datas

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, graphql, multi-tenant, aws-appsync

I want to develop a unique Flutter application for multiple tenants. All the datas and server will be on AWS. For security reasons, I would like to separate datas from one tenant to another. At this step, I see 2 options:

- having one GraphQL schema and multiple tables (one per tenant)
- having one GraphQL schema and multiple AWS account (one per tenant)

Also, a specific requirement to have in mind is the possible cross roles between tenants: one user could be an admin for tenant1 and a simple user for tenant2

In both case, the problem I encountered is to know how to switch from one tenant data to another tenant data. I think about having a login form with credentials and a kind of select input, but how to use this paramater with AWS to access the right data?